# Run a program on SQL Server 2008 when the program was writen to run on SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server

My program was written to work on SQL Server 2012 (v11.1) Express. I need to run it on SQL Server 2008 (v10.x).

I have installed the v11.1 ms driver 64. How if at all can I make this work.

Thanks in advance.

Donald s. Bossen

Comment: If the code uses nothing specific to SQL Server 2012, it will simply work. Later versions of the client drivers support connecting to earlier versions. If it does use functionality only available on SQL Server 2008, then obviously you're in trouble, and you need to identify what it uses and whether that can be done in some other way.

Comment: Just a comment of warning: SQL Server 2008 R2 is due to be end of life 9th July 2019 so any move from 2012 into 2008 will likely leave you needing to move it again or remain out of support after this date